# insert into sql table column as GUID

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net

I have tried with ado.net create table columnName with unique name. as uniquename I use `new Guid()`

```
    Guid sysColumnName = new Guid();
    sysColumnName = Guid.NewGuid();

    string stAddColumn = "ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " ADD " + sysColumnName.ToString() + " " + convertedColumnType + "  NULL";
    SqlCommand cmdAddColumn = new SqlCommand(stAddColumn, con);
    cmdAddColumn.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

and it fails:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '-'.
>      в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>      в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)

now question, how can i fix it, or how can use different way to create unique column?

Comment: Are you are trying to dynamically add columns to a table, and name the column a guid value? **don't do it** this is a very bad idea!

Comment: so you're trying to create a column where the name is a GUID?

Comment: because, I'm going to create database with arbitrary structure. and for this solution i create meta database. this meta database, like a dictionary. all information about tables and columns. i think, it is simplest update meta database, than rename TableName and ColumnName later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `[...]` to escape the column name that contains minus signs, or better still: don't create columns (or tables) with random names.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the dashes with underscores

```
var sysColumnName = Guid.NewGuid.ToString().Replace('-', '_');
```

Also, you shouldn't be creating sql in this way.  You should be using [parameterized commands](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This will format guid without "-" signs:

```
string columnName = Guid.ToString("N")
```

But it is bad practice to create columns with random names, are you sure you a going the right way?